# Location app for family members

Tags: security, geolocation

Is there any Android app which allows any family member to get my real-time location if installed ? Or is there any way to allow it ?

Comment: You can do this through Google+. Just enable your location to be shared to particular people in your "circle" and you will be able to have a real time view of each other's location.

Comment: Could elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7326816?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) should help explain how you can share your location with other people who have a Google account and are in your Google contacts.